# modifier subdivision surface not working

Tags: modeling

my subsurface division is not working as in I try to use it but it just does not even show the resulting mesh before being applied I would appreciate any help.
[image]

Comment: please put your file here

Comment: iam sorry i dont know how to put blender files here

Comment: if you can help by looking at the pic I would appreciate it

Comment: put that on google drive or so and send the link

Comment: ok give me a sec

Comment: tell me if it does not work

Comment: its a local link!!!!

Comment: Use this site for uploading http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/. Once done you'll obtain a link that can be pasted here.

Comment: does this one work?

Comment: can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

Uncheck *"simplify"* in the render settings:

[image]

Comment: thank you so much